# Asp.net mvc Details method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working on a project, where I have used the default routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

I have a users controller and methods like Index, create and details

I dont want to create links like http://mysite/users/details/111/somename 
instead i want to create http://mysite/users/111/somename
like stackoverflow kind of url. 
I know I can achieve by registering a route  like this (before default route)

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "UsersDetails",                                              // Route name
            "Users/{id}/{name}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Users", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

but then all my other urls start creating problem. for example if i have url 
http://somesite/users/registersuccess

Is there in workaround for this issue, or I should register all the urls.

Regards

Parminder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need a constraint on your `id` parameter for your routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "UsersDetails",
    "Users/{id}/{name}",
    new { controller = "Users", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional, name = UrlParameter.Optional }, 
    new { id="\d+" }
    );
```

Then your other routes wouldn't be affected.